# Perl - Generic subroutine which can aggregate the records and print

Tags: perl

We receive a data file from our legacy system and we process it and load it in a database. The input file (say input.txt) can be bifurcated column-wise into two parts – the first being the data columns and the second being the numbers columns. The processing that we do on this file is to drop some of the data columns and aggregate the numbers for the columns remaining (so that each record is a unique record).

The tab delimited input file input.txt is shown below (column0 to column4 are the data columns and column5 to column7 are the numbers column):

```
a   b   c   h   n   1.99    2.99    9
a   b   c   k   q   100 100 10
a   b   c   m   s   9.99    8.99    11
a   b   d   i   o   0.01    0.01    12
a   b   d   j   p   -12.19  11.11   13
a   b   e   l   r   9   9   14
```

The tab delimited output file output.txt is shown below:

```
a   b   c   111.98  111.98
a   b   d   -12.18  11.12
a   b   e   9   9
```

The following perl script aggregates the numbers by keeping column0, column1 and column2. The script is working fine.

```
use strict;

my $INPUT_FILE=shift @ARGV || die "You must supply the input as the first argument!!!\n";
my $OUTPUT_FILE=shift @ARGV || die "You must supply the output file as the second argument!!!\n";

open(my $out, ">", $OUTPUT_FILE) or die "Cannot open $OUTPUT_FILE for writing!\n";
open(my $in, "<", $INPUT_FILE) or die "Cannot open $INPUT_FILE for processing!\n";

my $data;
while (<$in>) 
{
s/\r?\n$//;
my @cols = split(/\t/);
$data->{$cols[0]}->{$cols[1]}->{$cols[2]}->[0] += $cols[5];
$data->{$cols[0]}->{$cols[1]}->{$cols[2]}->[1] += $cols[6];
}
close $in;


foreach my $lev1 (sort keys %{$data})
{
foreach my $lev2 (sort keys %{$data->{$lev1}})
{
    foreach my $lev3 (sort keys %{$data->{$lev1}->{$lev2}})
    {
        my $dataVal = $data->{$lev1}->{$lev2}->{$lev3}->[0];
        my $dataVal2 = $data->{$lev1}->{$lev2}->{$lev3}->[1];
        print $out "$lev1\t$lev2\t$lev3\t$dataVal\t$dataVal2\n";
    }
}
}
close $out;
```

Question: We apply the same logic in many different perl scripts. I want to create a generic subroutine which can be sourced in all those different script using “require” statement. The subroutine should aggregate and print the output. This subroutine should accept the arguments as to which columns I need for aggregation (currently column0 to column2) and the numbers from which columns should be aggregated (currently column5 and column6). Please advice.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a Perl module? If you are, you are doing it in a very roundabout way. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html

Comment: No, I just want to have a subroutine. We have a library of subroutines and I will add this new subroutine to it.

Comment: Please show us what you have written of the subroutine so far and what the problems were that stopped you from doing it successfully. SO is not a "do my work for me so I can get paid" site.

Comment: @DVK: Please do not attempt to do it then. I already have a working solution which is shown above and I am getting paid for it. I am just trying to improve it and I am really stumped there and that's why I turned to SO for help.

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach the problem is to begin by consolidating all of your parameters. Rather than scattering constants like 0, 5, 6, and `"\t"` throughout your program, bundle them up.

```
my %opt = (
    input_file  => 'input.dat',
    output_file => 'output.dat',
    keep_cols   => [0,1,2],
    agg_cols    => [5,6],
    join_char   => "\t",
);
```

Then you might think about how you would make your current script more modular -- something along these lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;  # Don't forget this.

run(@ARGV);

sub run {
    my %opt = get_args(@_);
    $opt{data} = read_input_file(%opt);
    write_output_file(%opt);
}

sub get_args {
}

sub read_input_file {
}

sub write_output_file {
}
```

Finally, I would suggest that you flatten your data structure. Rather than using a multi-level hash, which can be a bit awkward to type and read, simply join your various hash keys into a composite string, using any safe delimiter. Inside `read_input_file()`, you might have some code like this:

```
my @cols = split $opt{join_char}, $line;
my $i = 0;
my $k = join $opt{join_char}, @cols[ @{$opt{keep_cols}} ];
$data{$k}[$i ++] += $_ for @cols[ @{$opt{agg_cols }} ];
```

Comment: @FM: Thanks. This is how I initially attempted the solution. The input file is about 40000 lines and the script used to take huge amount of time to process and that's when I changed my approach to use the multi-level hash and found that multi-level hash has less turnaround time. And I should not forget you to thank again for not giving me the shit of SO is not a "do my work for me so I can get paid" site.

Comment: @sachin Unless the lines are extremely long, 40,000 lines is not very many. I suspect the slowness of your previous solution was coming from something other than the approach I outlined -- but that's just a hunch. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt on it using DBD::CSV. I wrapped it in a Moose class as that is what I wanted to try.

```
 package MyDataParser;

 use Moose;
 use MooseX::Types::Path::Class;

 use DBI;

 has _dbd => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Object', lazy_build => 1,);

 has data_file => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Path::Class::File', required => 1, coerce => 1);

 has label_columns => (
    traits => ['Array'],
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'ArrayRef[Int]',
    required => 1,
    handles => {
      list_label_columns => 'elements',
      add_label_column => 'push', 
      }
     );

 has data_columns => (
   traits => ['Array'],
   is => 'rw',
   isa => 'ArrayRef[Int]',
   required => 1,
   handles => {
     list_data_columns => 'elements',
     add_data_column => 'push',
    }
  );

  has _sql_query => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', lazy_build => 1,);

  sub get_totals {

   my $self = shift;

   my $ar = $self->_dbd->selectall_arrayref($self->_sql_query);
   die $DBI::errstr if $DBI::err;


    foreach my $row (@$ar) {
       print "@$row\n";

   }

   }

   sub _build__dbd  {

     my $self = shift;

     my $dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:");
        $dbh->{csv_tables}{data} = {
            sep_char    => "\t",
            file        => $self->data_file,
            col_names   => ['column1' .. 'column8'],
        };

        return $dbh;

     }

  sub _build__sql_query {

    my $self = shift;

    my @label_column_names = map {'column' . $_} $self->list_label_columns;
    my @data_columns = map {"SUM(column$_)"} $self->list_data_columns;

    my $labels_str = join ', ', @label_column_names;
    my $data_columns_str = join ', ', @data_columns;

    my $query = qq/SELECT $labels_str, $data_columns_str FROM data GROUP BY $labels_str/;


    return $query;
   }



 package main;

 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my $df = MyDataParser->new(data_file => 'data.txt', label_columns => [1,2,3], data_columns => [6,7,8]);
  $df->get_totals;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, your current solution can be generalized. The first issue is to identify the hard-coded pieces of your program that may well be required to vary in future projects.

Only you know for sure what you want to generalize, but FM's hash of options offers you a very good guess.  Let me focus on two of these options,

```
key_cols   => [0,1,2],  
agg_cols   => [5,6],
```

where I've changed `keep_cols` to `key_cols`, since we're going to use them as keys in our data hash.

Think of your current statements

```
# version 1, key cols and agg cols hardcoded

$data->{$cols[0]}->{$cols[1]}->{$cols[2]}->[0] += $cols[5]; 
$data->{$cols[0]}->{$cols[1]}->{$cols[2]}->[1] += $cols[6];
```

as loops over the arrays referenced by these two options.  Looping over the `agg_cols` is the easy part:

```
# version 2, generic agg cols, but key cols still hardcoded

my @agg_cols = @$opt{agg_cols};
for my $i (0..$#agg_cols}) {
    $data->{$cols[0]}->{$cols[1]}->{$cols[2]}->[$i] += $cols[$agg_col[$i]];
}
```

Now to loop over the `key_cols`, just make a temporary copy of your $data ref, and index it more deeply on each pass:

```
# version 3, generic agg cols and key cols
my @agg_cols = @$opt{agg_cols};
my @key_cols = @$opt{key_cols};

my $current_ref = $data;
for my $key_col (@key_cols) {
    $current_ref = $current_ref->{$cols[$key_col]};
}

for my $i (0..$#agg_cols}) {
    $current_ref->[$i] += $cols[$agg_col[$i]];
}
```

This code belongs inside your `while <$in>` loop, except that you will want to refactor by reading your `agg_cols` and `key_cols` options just once at the top.

Comment: Thanks for this but what I find is $data->{$cols[0]}->{$cols[1]}->{$cols[2]}->[$i] part is kind of hard-coded in the sense that it will always assume that it is a three level deep hash.

Comment: @sachin: I developed a generic solution in two steps, and it looks to me like you stopped at my first step.  I think I'll add some comments to my code.